# Java - How do I set a container pane color from another method?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jpanel, containers

I have a Container pane and I'm using gridbaglayout.  to set the color I pane.setbackground but i want to do this from another method, and action handling method.  pane.setbackground won't work.  what do i do?  thanks.

```
package mcve;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class mcve extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

final static  boolean shouldFill = true;
final static  boolean shouldWeightX = true;
final static   boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;
static JFrame frame;
static JButton color1, color2, exit;

public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) throws IOException {
    if(RIGHT_TO_LEFT){
        pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    }

    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    if (shouldFill){
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
    }


    // here i can do it.
    pane.setBackground(Color.black);

    color1 = new JButton("color1");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=0;
    color1.setActionCommand("color1");
    color1.addActionListener(new mcve());
    pane.add(color1, c);

    color2 = new JButton("color2");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
    c.gridx=1;
    c.gridy=0;
    color2.setActionCommand("color2");
    color2.addActionListener(new mcve());
    pane.add(color2, c);

    exit = new JButton("Exit");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
    c.gridx=1;
    c.gridy=0;
    exit.setActionCommand("exit");
    exit.addActionListener(new mcve());
    pane.add(exit, c);

}

public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

   if ("exit".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
       System.exit(0);
       }
   else if ("color1".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
      // I DON'T KNOW
       }
   else if ("color2".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
      // I DON'T KNOW
       }

}

private static void createAndShowGUI(){
 frame = new JFrame("MCVE");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 try {
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 frame.pack();
 frame.setResizable(false);
 frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It sounds like you need to keep a reference to the panel.  For anything more definite, I'd need to see an MCVE.

Comment: okay i did it posting it on thread

Comment: Note that `ContainerPaneColorTest` is a much better class name than `mcve`.  That name clashes with other code I have in my 'junk code' directory..

Comment: Stop sabotaging your questions (i.e. to remove relevant code) and start accepting answers!

Answer (score 3):

```
   else if ("color1".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
       frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
       }
   else if ("color2".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
       frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
       }
```

..is one way to do it.

Comment: thank you so much man!  i don't know i wasn't even thinking lol.  thank you.